# No swap space reported?

Tags: linux, hard-disk, raid

So I had a raid 1 configuration and one hard disk failed.
Now I have replaced it and issued the following command to rebuild the first two partition:

```
mdadm /dev/md1 --manage --add /dev/sda1
```

and

```
mdadm /dev/md2 --manage --add /dev/sdb2
```

Both rebuild are ok. `fdisk -l` reports this:

```
root@rescue:~# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1.8 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1  *          4096   20975616   20971521    10G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2         20975617 1464092672 1443117056 688.1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda3       1464092673 1465144064    1051392 513.4M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 698.7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00025c91

Device     Boot      Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1  *          4096   20975616   20971521    10G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb2         20975617 1464092672 1443117056 688.1G fd Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb3       1464092673 1465144064    1051392 513.4M 82 Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/md2: 688.1 GiB, 738875867136 bytes, 1443116928 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk /dev/md1: 10 GiB, 10737352704 bytes, 20971392 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

I also did:

```
mkswap  /dev/sda3
swapon -a
```

But if I type `free` I got no swap

```
           total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:       4025812     251340    3774472      11412      42456      63468
-/+ buffers/cache:     145416    3880396
Swap:            0          0          0
```

Answer (score 2):

`swapon -a` will add swap entries from `/etc/fstab`

You would need a line like

```
/dev/sda3    none    swap    sw      0 0
```

for `swapon -a` to work.

You can *temporarily* add a swap device with

```
swapon /dev/sda3
```

but this will disappear when you next reboot.

## SIDE NOTE

I notice your swap isn't on raid.  If you lose a disk then your swap will corrupt.  I'd recommend building another md array (eg `md3`) built out of `sda3` and `sdb3` and then using `md3` as swap.

In my case I have

```
/dev/sda5              66         131      522240   fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb5              66         131      522240   fd  Linux raid autodetect
```

These are in md3

```
md3 : active raid1 sdb5[1] sda5[0]
      521920 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]
```

And I swap with

```
/dev/md3        swap       swap    defaults              0 0
```

Comment: Thanks! can you give me the list of comman to build md3 and then add them for swap?

Comment: You would build md3 the same as any other array with `mdadm`; eg `mdadm --create /dev/md3 --level=1 --raid-devices=2 /dev/sda3 /dev/sdb3`  (untested; use at your own risk).  Change the partition type (via `fdisk`) to type `fd` for auto-detection at boot time.  Then `mkswap /dev/md3` then add the line to `fstab` and `swapon -a`

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't have swap partition perfectly created, else it will show as

```
[root@localhost ~]# swapon -s
Filename                                Type            Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda3                               partition       2031608 2040    -1
```

Check by `swapon -s` for a list of current swap devices and other relevant information.

Do your swap partition is listed with `df` ? check there too

Use tools like `partprobe` -- to re-read the file system without rebooting.
or `gparted`, `resize2fs` can also help you out